# Can jutsu affect superman?

Tags: dc, superman

So this question is partially a two parter.

**1. Do chi-powered abilities act like magic in the world of Superman?**

And if so...

**2. Given that superman is known to be weak to magic, is Superman affected by chi-powered abilities in much the same way?**

I am curious too if there was ever anything in the comics or canon of Superman where he had fought someone with *ninja-like* abilities (especially similar to those seen in Naruto).

Comment: It looks to me like *Shark vs. Gorilla* question..

Comment: I think it's ok as written; the question is asking for references from Superman canon, not merely speculation.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - It's better with the secondary references removed. I'm sure Superman will have [fought ninjas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGyDGoZ8hYA) and martial arts experts before.

Comment: [Iron Fist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_Fist_%28comics%29)'s powers are chi based I think. But we'd need a marvel / dc crossover to test them out on Superman.

Comment: Superman is not "weak" to magic. He is still able to perform all of his super abilities, but depending on the magic, he may be able to be affected in a fashion similar to anyone else. Energy bolts can hit him and hurt him but where they would kill a normal person, he still gains a measure of his invulnerability. Magical weapons can harm him and even cut him, but with his host of other abilities, he can opt to stay out of range, speed-blitz his opponents, freeze them where they stand, etc. Magic affects him, it does not usually completely disable him as it would a normal target.

Comment: I'd love to see a Destroyer(Remo Williams) vs. Superman story!

Answer (score 14):

In [The Question (Vol 2 #1-6)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Question_Vol_2) we see Luthor building a chi-based weapon. Superman later acknowledges that it could (theoretically) have hurt him, although he doesn't seem especially worried about it.

[image]

And in The Lois and Clarke : The New Adventures of Superman episode "[Chi of Steel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0635141/)", we encounter Chen Chow, a ninja-like thief who uses the power of chi (chanelled through two bracelets) to fight superman. It's very effective.

[image]

Comment: In the Lois and Clark episode, it was very effective at first.  After Clark learns to control his own chi at a rudimentary level, it stops working on him.